# How to extract data using python from a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have been having troubles with extracting reading/manipulating/extracting data from a txt file.  In the text file it has a general header with various information that is setup something like this below just as an example:

```
~ECOLOGY
~LOCATION      
LAT:           59  
LONG:          23

~PARAMETERS
Area.          8
Distribution.  3
Diversity.     5

~DATA  X        Y        CONF     DECID    PEREN
       3        6        1        3        0       
       7        2        4        2        1
       4        8        0        6        2
       9        9        6        2        0
       2        3        2        5        4  
       6        5        0        2        7 
       7        1        2        4        2
```

I want to be able to extract the headers of the columns and use the headers of the columns as an index or key since sometimes the types of column data can change between files and the amount of rows of data can fluctuate as well.  I want to be able to read the data in each column so that pending on location I can sum or add columns such as show below and export it as a separate file:

```
~DATA  X        Y        CONF     DECID    PEREN    TOTAL 
       3        6        1        3        0        4       
       7        2        4        2        1        7
       4        8        0        6        2        8 
       9        9        6        2        0        8 
       2        3        2        5        4        11
       6        5        0        2        7        9
       7        1        2        4        2        8
```

Any suggestions?

This is what I have so far:

```
E = open("ECOLOGY.txt", "r")
with open(path) as E:
    for i, line in enumerate(E):
        sep_lines = line.rsplit()
        if "~DATA" in sep_lines:
            key =(line.rsplit())
            key.remove('~DATA')
            for j, value in enumerate(key):
                print (j,value)
            print (key)
            dict = {L: v for v, L in enumerate(key)}
            print(dict)
```

Comment: Are you able/allowed to use additional modules or do you have to use built-in modules? In the first case, I would suggest having a look at `pandas`, in the second have a look at the `csv` module. What did you try so far? Do have any code snippet you already worked on? If you do not need to handle data and only want to cut off the header resp. extract data you do not need to use `pandas` or `csv`. In that case I suggest reading the file and just skip the header lines.

Comment: But what is your question? What is the trouble you've been having? You can post the code you're having problems with.

Comment: I haven't used pandas before, and was trying to just use the built in modules.  I'm trying to read/print each column of data, and be able to manipulate it and export it into a different file.

Answer (score 0):

Life would be much easier for you if you learned a smidgen of Pandas. But you *can* do it without.

```
with open('ttl.txt') as ttl:
    for _ in range(10):
        next(ttl)
    first = True
    for line in ttl:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if first:
            first = False
            labels = line.split()+['TOTAL']
            fmt = 7*'{:<9s}'
            print (fmt.format(*labels))
        else:
            numbers = [int(_) for _ in line.split()]
            total = sum(numbers[-3:])
            other_items = numbers + [total]
            fmt = 6*'{:<9d}'
            fmt = '{:<9s}'+fmt
            print (fmt.format('', *other_items))
```

```
~DATA    X        Y        CONF     DECID    PEREN    TOTAL    
         3        6        1        3        0        4        
         7        2        4        2        1        7        
         4        8        0        6        2        8        
         9        9        6        2        0        8        
         2        3        2        5        4        11       
         6        5        0        2        7        9        
         7        1        2        4        2        8
```

`next` skips lines in the input file. You can use `split()` to split input lines on whitespace, the use formatting to put items back together as you want them.

Comment: You should really ask another question if you'd rather know how to do this with Pandas. I'm not a good one to ask about tutorials because I've been programming for many years and I don't use them much, even for new things I need to learn. I would suggest putting a question on, say, quora.com, since questions like that are not allowed here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

This a very basic, frail, format depending solution. But I hope it can help you.

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    data_part_reached = False
    for line in f:
        if "~DATA" in line:
            column = [[elem] for elem in line.split(" ") if elem not in (" ", "", "\n", "~DATA")]
            data_part_reached = True
        elif data_part_reached:
            values = [int(elem) for elem in line.split(" ") if elem not in (" ", "", "\n")]
            for i in range(len(columns)):
                columns[i].append(values[i])

columns =
[['X', 3, 7, 4, 9, 2, 6, 7],
 ['Y', 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 5, 1],
 ['CONF', 1, 4, 0, 6, 2, 0, 2],
 ['DECID', 3, 2, 6, 2, 5, 2, 4],
 ['PEREN', 0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 7, 2],
 ['TOTAL', 4, 7, 8, 8, 11, 9, 8]]
```

This will get you a list of lists where the first element of each list is the header and the rest are the values. I casted the values to `int` since you said you want to operate with them. You can turn this list into a dict where the `key` is the header and the list of values of each column are the `value` if you want, like this.

```
d = {}
for column in columns:
    d[column.pop(0)] = column

d =
{'DECID': [3, 2, 6, 2, 5, 2, 4],
 'PEREN': [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 7, 2],
 'CONF':  [1, 4, 0, 6, 2, 0, 2],
 'X':     [3, 7, 4, 9, 2, 6, 7],
 'TOTAL': [4, 7, 8, 8, 11, 9, 8],
 'Y':     [6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 5, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a empty dictionary to store all needed data.
Read from the file object as `E` and loop until you reach a line starting with `~DATA`.
Then split the header items, append `TOTAL` and then break from the loop.
Create a list to store the remaining data.
Loop to split the data and then append the sum total.
The list will append each list of data.
Loop ends and then adds to list of lists to the dictionary.

```
dic = {}
with open("ECOLOGY.txt") as E:
    for line in E:
        if line[:5] == '~DATA':
            dic['header'] = line.split()[1:] + ['TOTAL']
            break
    data = []
    for line in E:
        cols = line.split()
        cols.append(sum([int(num) for num in cols[2:]]))
        data.append(cols)
    dic['data'] = data
```

The dictionary will be i.e. {'header': [...], 'data': [[...], ...]}

edit: Added missing dic declaration at the beginning of code.